# Ember js default bundle

Tags: javascript, ember.js, frameworks

I make ember project from this [guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/getting-started/) . But i have something like default application - routes and etc . How can i delete this and start from scratch ?

Comment: Have you tried their [Todo MVC guide](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/getting-started/)  as a sample?

Answer (score 0):

This guide is how to start ember using ember-cli. I am sure this is the main road to build ember apps. Ember-cli has conventional directory-files structure, you could see it when you run `ember new my-app-name`. For example all routes are in the `app/routes` directory and etc. You may delete all files/directories you don't need, but all files you use (or ember-cli uses) must be in the conventional directory.

As far as I understand, you'd like to begin with something simpler. You can start with simple html file, using any default jsbin you like, for example http://emberjs.jsbin.com/?html,css,js,output

Community usually use such jsbins for demonstrating issues. See jsbins collection here https://gist.github.com/rwjblue/8816372